# Passing string to a REST API that consumes application/json

Tags: java, json, rest

I have an interface that looks something like this:

```
@Path("/myapi")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public interface MyRestApi {

    /// Some methods here that accept complex object and work fine

    @GET
    @Path("/methodwithstring")    
    public void methodWithString(final String thumbprint,
        @Context final HttpServletResponse response);


}
```

When I pass a string to the `methodWithString`method we get a string that looks like this **"some-string"**. The problem is the quotes, the string arrives to the method surrounded with ". I would like to understand how can I pass it without the surrounding ".

I guess that happens because the class consumes "application/json". That's the first time we pass a string as a parameter and we don't know how to work around this issue.

Comment: Either u have to covert String to JSON at client side. Or replace quotes at server side. I would do the first.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao - Do you mean I need to create a wrapper object that wrappes the string parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try move `@Consumes("application/json")` inside the class

and make methodWithString `@Consumes("text/plain")`

i guess this should work.

```
@Path("/myapi")
@Produces("application/json")
public interface MyRestApi {

    /// Some methods here that accept complex object and work fine
    // @Consumes("application/json")
    // public void somemethods() ...

    @GET
    @Path("/methodwithstring")
    @Consumes("text/plain")   
    public void methodWithString(final String thumbprint,
        @Context final HttpServletResponse response);
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Also on my client side, I'm using restTemplate with only jackson converter. I added StringHttpMessageConverter as well.